# Adding tab in ternary operator inside c# webgrid

Tags: c#, webgrid

any help will be appreciated cause I've already spent quite a few hours with this stuff

```
grid.Column(columnName: "", header: "Name", style: "text-align-left", format: (item) => (item.ParentCategoryId == null) ? @item.Name : ("--" + @item.Name))
```

The thing is that I'm trying to add a tab to the "--" (or at least change these dashes for the tab itself) in order to appear indented, but can't sort it out.

---

**Addition (because I'm not allowed to answer my own question)**

Well, sure not the cleanest one and wouldn't be able to say why, but this code works so I add it for it may be of some help for someone (the text labels inside the else statement could be changed for @: but then you should take care of the correct line returns)

```
grid.Column(columnName: "", header: "Name", style: "text-align-left", format: 
    @<text>
        @if(@item.ParentCategoryId == null)
            {@item.Name}
        else
            {<text>&nbsp; &nbsp; --@item.Name</text>}
    </text>),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using "\t" in place of the "--".

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jupiter. Actually I've tried to add this \t in all the ways I could think of but with no joy. Lately I've been trying wit &nbsp but with the same fortune!!